# create one button and method

Tags: java, android

I am new in java or android just create one demo.

I found good example on google: https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example

Now I want to create one button and method in Java and on them I click the button and the method is invoked and will show a *hello world* message.

I need good help on this because I don't know where I want to change and where to put code for create button.

Comment: Now 5 people are trying to make an Android tutorial for you... This is not what the site is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your problem but I assume you want to define click listener with method which prints Hello World message.

1. Include `android:onClick` attribute in your Button inside XML layout.

   For example: `android:onClick="btnHelloWorldClick"`
2. Define method in Activity class with the same name given in android:onClick attribute.

For example:

```
public void btnHelloWorldClick(View v)
{
  System.out.println("Hello world");  
  // or Toast.makeText(this, "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: this function where i put.....?

Comment: @user2436689 I think I have written *define method in Activity class*!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code,

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

and your layout,

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this question is most likely to get closed but here's what you need to know
To handle the clicks for any view let it be a Relative layout,button,textview ,etc you need to implement the onClickListener and perform function inside the onclick function of the interface

there are many ways you can set onclick listeners:

1 Let you activity implement onclickListener it will ask you to implement onClick function and you can run your function there

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int clickedId = v.getId();
        switch (clickedId) {
        case R.id.nearbyButtonHome:
            nearbyButtonAction();
            break;

        case R.id.cgExButtonHome:
            cgExButtonAction();
            break;

        case R.id.styleButtonHome:
            styleButtonAction();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

2  you can set the onclick listeners on button object directly

```
close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dismiss();
    }
});
```

3 you can add a attribute to button tag in layout file

```
android:onClick="func1"
```

and in your activity create this function.

this is all about the button clicks

Comment: thanks man but can you help me where i put this code android:onClick function in res/xml/keyboard.xml like...

Comment: I suggest you should watch this channel it will help you understand the android and you will be able to start within 1-2 hour http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf7z_mrce00&list=SPE953C0B85B50AB62

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

First add attribute "android:onClick="btnHelloWorldClick"" in Button controller in xml layout.

For Example:

Answer (score 0):

Define button in xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
  setContentView(R.id.activity_main);
  Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do something or call a function defined. 
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Define onclick attribute for button in xml

activtiy_main

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="btnClick" // method
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   public void btnClick(View v)
   {
      // do something 
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

To create a button programatically

MainActivity

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
   RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
   // Define relative layout in xml layout file.
   Button b = new Button(MainActivity.this);
   rl.addView(b);
   // button click using annonymous inner class   
   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do something or call a function defined.
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
});
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Your class can also implement OnClickListener. In that case

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 { 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
  button.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  @Override 
  public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) //returns int
  {
    case R.id.button1 :
          // do something or call a function defined.
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    break; 
  }      
  }
  }
```